# Configuring JBoss Application Server 5.1.0 to run as a windows service?

Tags: windows, service, jboss, application-server

How do you configure jboss application server to run as a windows service (e.g. JBoss AS 5.1.0)?

Answer (score 1):

See [the community wiki](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RunJBossAsAServiceOnWindows) for the available options.